# How to edit Jupyter Notebook metadata in PyCharm?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

More specifically, I am trying to edit the authors of a notebook. Using the Jupyter web interface, I can accomplish this like so:

Edit -> Edit Notebook Metadata -> add relevent tags (e.g. "authors": [{"name": "Author Name"}],)

How can I accomplish this using PyCharm?

I am using PyCharm's Jupyter add on provided with PyCharm pro

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on notebook in the project pane
2. Press mark as Plain Text
3. Close notebook tab (by pressing the x on the tab)
4. Open notebook by double clicking the notebook in the project pane

Once you're done editing the notebook's source, repeat steps above but press "Mark as Jupyter Notebook"

Comment: It seems nowadays this is called "Override File Type", for which one can choose "Plain Text". Indeed, I can then paste a raw Notebook. But saving and closing, choosing "Revert File Type Override", and re-opening the file still makes PyCharm show some old cached version. Closing and re-opening the project does not help, but restarting PyCharm does. Editing outside of PyCharm is quicker. :-)